# .htaccess rewrite rule with regex not working, returns 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I tried to resize an image with timthumb library.
I can use it directly via the following URL

`http://localhost/study/server/resize/thumb.php?src=http://localhost/study/server/product/1/1/orig-1.jpg&w=160&h=130`

and it works fine.

But when I rewrite my url like this

```
http://localhost/study/server/resize/160x130/r/product/1/1/orig-1.jpg
```

and add

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(resize) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^resize/(.*)x(.*)/r/(.*) resize/thumb.php?src=http://localhost/study/server/$3&h=$2&w=$1&c=1
</IfModule>
```

unfortunately this rule return 404 error

Comment: what server you can use wamp or xammp...?

Comment: ubuntu apache2 httpd

Answer (score 0):

Use this `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^study/server/resize/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/r/product/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ 
/study/server/resize/thumb.php?src=/study/server/product/$3/$4/$5&w=$1&h=$2 [L]
```

**group 1**  matches the width, zero or more digits
**group 2**  matches the height, zero or more digits
**group 3**  matches the first digit after /product/, one digit, you can modify if needed
**group 4**  matches the second digit after /product/, one digit, you can modify if needed
**group 5**  matches the filename

This condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(resize) [NC]
```

is not needed